# Converting TensorFlow datasets to images and labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The objective is to train cats and dogs datasets from TensorFlow datasets for which I need to convert the data to Images and labels. I need to build a function that returns images and labels from the 'features' of TensorFlow datasets and create training datasets from it. Please run the code for further details.

The infrastructure will resize all images to 224x224 with 3 bytes of color depth. Make sure your input layer trains images to that specification.

[similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669745/unsupported-return-value-from-function-passed-to-dataset-map)

Code:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_name = 'cats_vs_dogs'
dataset, info = tfds.load(name=dataset_name, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN, with_info=True)
def preprocess(features):

    // this is where the code must be.

def solution_model():
    train_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess).batch(32)
```

This is where I will code the model and give training datasets as input.

Comment: the kaggle site has a solution using tensorflow and using keras https://www.kaggle.com/priyankabnl/dogs-vs-cats-using-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```html
def preprocess(features):
    image = features['image']
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224))
    image = image / 255.0
    return image, features['label']
```